# Kafka producer and consumer on different Kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

Would Kafka need to be installed on the consumer cluster?

Presently the same cluster YAML configuration is:

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: sample-topic
spec:
  type: bindings.kafka
  version: v1
  metadata:
  # Kafka broker connection setting
  - name: brokers
    value: dapr-kafka.kafka:9092
  # consumer configuration: topic and consumer group
  - name: topics
    value: sample
  - name: consumerGroup
    value: group1
  # publisher configuration: topic
  - name: publishTopic
    value: sample
  - name: authRequired
    value: "false"
```

On different clusters, does each cluster require only either "name: publishTopic" or "name: consumerGroup" and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Dapr, but Kafka does not need installed in k8s, or any specific location. Your only requirement should be client connectivity to that bootstrap-servers list.

According to the [Kafka Binding](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-bindings/kafka/)  spec, consumerGroup is for incoming events, and publishTopic is for outgoing, so two different use cases, although one app should be able to have both event types. If the app only uses incoming or outgoing events, then use the appropriate binding for that case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply: for event types im asking if they should be in two YAMLs separately for two apps.


My first question is whether Kafka also has to be installed on the consumer cluster, or only the producer cluster. (my question is not Does Kafka require Kubernetes)

Comment: My point is that Kafka can be installed **anywhere**. Could be outside k8s, inside one k8s cluster, or both clusters. Doesn't matter as long as both apps have network connectivity to the clusters defined in the properties... And like I said, if your app is only a producer or consumer, then you would only need one, and if the app does both, then use both.